# Integrallity in convex hull of a linear programming

Tags: linear-programming, convex-hull, integral, integer-programming

How is it possible to formulate the convex hull of a linear programming (LP) problem to be integral? Are there any general techniques to perform this?

Comment: Do you want to find a formulation for the convex hull of an integer program?

Comment: Yes. In other word, the convex hull of LP-relaxation of an integer program to be integral.

Comment: In general such an ideal formulation is hard to find. I think there is no standard way for it. Solvers usually do some preprocessing to tighten the formulation.

Comment: Could you give an example of what you expect? The convex hull of the domain of an ILP is a convex polyedron (a subset of R^n), whereas an integral is (to me, note that I am not a native English speaker) a real number, usually the volume of a set; clearly one cannot "be" the other.

Comment: it seems to me that there is a misunderstanding here. By "Integrallity" we mean "to be integer". You can see relevant "terms" in the following paper (and also an example): http://pubsonline.informs.org/doi/abs/10.1287/ijoc.12.2.111.11896

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add a bit to Martin answer above (I think this is too long for a comment):

1. There is a general procedure that I know of, called Chvátal-Gomorry procedure, which allow to ultimately describe the convex hull by adding Gomorry cuts. This is very interesting theoretically; however, there is a well-known example where this procedure takes `n` step (a parameter in the LP) for a problem with two variables and two constraints, i.e. the number of cuts added cannot be bounded by the size of the problem.
2. Totally unimodular matrix are common in problems arising in graph theory, but it is certainly not a "general" method: you can convince yourself just by the definition that the coefficient of the `A` matrix must be 0, 1 or -1 in a TU matrix, which is usually not the case in a ILP of course.

Of course, since solving an LP is polynomial and solving an ILP is NP-complete, one cannot expect that there is a general efficient method to do what you expect, since that would almost reduce ILP to LP!

But if you are studiying a problem in particular, especially if it has a simple structure, it could be one of the "special cases" where one of the two methods above are effective.

I can provide further references at the end of the week if you are interested.

Comment: Dear @Nicolas, please do not hesitate at providing any information about topic. I'm very interested and that's why I'm asking such a question. Also, please base your alternative answer on _A_ matrix with binary coefficients and TU property.

Answer (score 3):

In the sense of a formulation, a linear program yields a polyhedron with (in general) fractional extreme points. If you want to solve exactly this problem, there is nothing to change /manipulate at the polyhedron.

If you have a (mixed) integer linear program (MIP), you may be interested in the description of the convex hull of its integer points. In general, this can be used for a fast solution process, since you can solve its linear relaxation without performing a branch and bound process afterwards.

This means, the linear relaxation of the MIP gives a polyhedron which contains this convex hull - and which itself needs not have integer extreme points. In many cases, you want to tighten this formulation towards the convex hull of the integer points, which is done by the usual solvers (e.g. by adding inequalities).
The aim is always to obtain a formulation of said convex hull. However, finding this formulation is generally NP-hard (so there are no known general techniques to obtain it easily). Especially this means, that the size of such a formulation (i.e., the amount of inequalities) can be exponential.

The are algorithms to compute convex hulls of integer points (or from general polyhedrons), but they are not simple and not "fast". Software, which can help you there is probably [Porta](http://www.iwr.uni-heidelberg.de/groups/comopt/software/PORTA/) or [Polymake](http://www.polymake.org/doku.php).

There are properties describing when polyhedrons/formulations are integer. E.g. one of these goes by the name of [total (dual) unimodularity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unimodular_matrix). Formulating your problem in such a way or identifying this property is not easy and I am not aware of any structural approaches for doing so.

I hope this helps :)

Kind regards,

Martin

Comment: To put in a nutshell, you did mentioned exactly my purpose: "you can solve its linear relaxation without performing a branch and bound process afterwards." Nice!

Comment: For me, the ultimate goal would be describing A (coefficients of variables in constraints) to hold such TU (totally uni-modular) property.